# How to install Adobe Acrobat Reader in Debian?

Tags: debian, pdf

I've got `deb http://debian-multimedia.org squeeze main` in "**/etc/apt/sources.list**", but `wajig update && wajig install acroread` results in:

```
E: Package ‘acroread’ has no installation candidate
```

What’s happening? Are there alternative repos?

Comment: Just to add a note that unless you _really_ need Adobe Reader's advanced features, you might want to try an alternative reader like Evince, ePDFview or (my favorite) Zathura, which besides being Free Software, are less likely to be target of PDF exploits (in part, because they don't support risky features like embedded scripting).

Comment: Note that Adobe Reader on Linux is dead, it has no security updates anymore. https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=843835

Answer (score 27, accepted):

***NOTE:** The 9.x branch of reader has been [EOL'd as of June 26, 2013](http://www.adobe.com/products/reader/tech-specs.html). If you need native Adobe Reader support on Linux, 9.x is your only option! 10 [doesn't list Linux as being supported](http://www.adobe.com/products/reader/tech-specs.html), and likely never will.  More on it too here: [Adobe abandons Linux](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/open-source/adobe-abandons-linux/10418).*

*Many may question the relevance of needing Adobe Reader but there are several use cases that the open source versions of reading tools simply do not provide. Signing documents, filling out forms, and printing are just a few of these use cases where your only option is to use Adobe Reader!*

---

To install Adobe Reader on Wheezy or higher you can use the following steps.

#### Step #1 - Download

Adobe maintains all the official versions of Adobe Reader on their FTP site so you can simply go there and download the latest version, packaged as a `.deb` file.

- [The primary URL for all versions of Adobe Reader](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/)
- [9.x versions of Adobe Reader](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/)

If you go to the 2nd URL above you'll get to a page that looks like this:

[image: ss #1]

From this page you can select whatever happens to be the latest version of Reader at the time you're attempting to do this. For this example we'll be downloading **9.5.5**, so we select that link.

This will take us to another page with the link, "enu". This denotes that we're downloading the English version of the tool. Apparently they only offer the package in this language. I'm not 100% on this particular point, but no matter, we press on.

[image: ss #2]

At this point we should be at this URL:

- ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/

From here we can download the `.deb` file. I typically do this using `wget` like so:

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

After doing this we should have the file, `AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb`. Now we're ready to install it.

#### Step #2 - Installation

The file we just downloaded is the 32-bit version of Adobe Reader. Adobe only provides Reader as a 32-bit binary, there is no 64-bit variant, but this is perfectly fine, we just need to install it a bit differently than most `.deb` packages.

1. First we need to add the 32-bit architecture to our system (multiarch), then update.

   ```
    $ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
    $ sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Now attempt to install Adobe Reader with either `dpkg` and `apt-get` OR `gdebi`.  If you pick the first option, it will require you to tell `apt-get` to fix any broken installed packages.  This would seem to be a hack, but it basically gets `apt` to do the heavy lifting for us and install/fix any missing or broken packages with relatively little fuss.  Alternatively, using the second method, `gdebi` will automatically resolve the dependencies.

   - **Using `dpkg` and `apt-get`:**

     ```
       $ sudo dpkg -i AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
       $ sudo apt-get install -f
     ```
   - **Using `gdebi`:**

     ```
       $ sudo apt-get install gdebi
       $ sudo gdebi AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
     ```
3. Now, attempting to launch acroread with

   ```
    $ acroread
   ```

   gives

   ```
    /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread: error while loading shared libraries: libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   ```

   Adobe forgot a dependency.
   We can figure out which package to install using `apt-file`.

   ```
    $ apt-file search libxml2.so.2
   ```

   which gives `libxml2`. So we do

   ```
    $ apt-get install libxml2:i386
   ```

   to install the i386 version of `libxml2`.
4. Now invoke `acroread` using a non-root account.

   ```
    $ acroread
   ```

   Here is a screenshot of Acrobat Reader running on Debian Wheezy.

NOTE: Adobe installs Acrobat Reader in `/opt`, which is icky, and in violation of the FHS.

[image: ss #3]

#### References

- [[SOLVED] how to install Adobe Acrobat Reader?](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=104362&sid=1bc16a1c92ef6658e00373e6dd0c41ee&start=15)
- [DebianAMD64FAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAMD64Faq)
- [Adobe Reader 9.5.4 on 64 bit Linux](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.user/452342)

Comment: I also had to do `sudo aptitude install lib32stdc++6` before I could run `acroread` on Debian: http://askubuntu.com/questions/371564/adobe-reader-not-initializing

Comment: I recommend installing Acroread 9.4.1, it has more features than other versions. Such as embedded flash and movie playback that were dropped later.

Comment: FTP links require username and password...

Comment: @rbaleksandar try with anonymous/anonymous

Comment: This still works with debian 10.

Comment: On debian 11, I had to install `sudo apt install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386`

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you have just added `main` to your sources.list.  I believe that `acroread` is in the non-free part of the respository, so you will want to add:

```
deb http://debian-multimedia.org squeeze non-free
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and then update and install.

Traditionally, even in third-party repos, `main` only includes files that conform to the [Debian Free Software Guidelines](http://www.debian.org/social_contract#guidelinesBlockquote).  While `non-free` contains

> Packages [that] have some onerous license condition restricting use or redistribution of the software.

(from http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages)

Comment: [thou shalt not use debian-multimedia](http://bits.debian.org/2013/06/remove-debian-multimedia.html)!!! btw, "debian-multimedia" has ceased to exist...

Comment: This no longer works for wheezy and higher. See my A, which does. Also deb-multimedia.org shouldn't be used as a repo! See this Debian mailing list thread for more info: http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-multimedia-maintainers/2012-May/026678.html

Comment: @umläute it has just changed its (host)name: http://deb-multimedia.org/

Comment: @Totor i know about the rename; my point was more that *thou shall not use repositories that are known to break your setup* (admittedly my link was failing to explain this, the one provided by slm is better)

Comment: @slm Nonesense. I have Jessie and `sudo apt-get install acroread` after adding the repo (change `squeeze` to `jessie`) and updating the packages.

Comment: @rbaleksandar read the mailing list thread. Debian-multimedia shouldn't be used.

Comment: I no longer use it...from approx 1 year. Just saying. LOL

Answer (score 3):

#### Note: This answer installs from the same repository which use to be at www.debian-multimedia.org, but has now renamed its domain to www.deb-multimedia.org. For more information on why this happened (and why this repository is no longer considered part of Debian), please see -  http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-multimedia-maintainers/2012-May/026678.html

I am running Jessie, here is how I get adobe reader to work. The process should be very similar for Wheezy. I see no need to download from the Adobe website, as the `acroread` package from http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ can still work ok.

The relevant `sources.list` line is:

```
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org testing main non-free
```

You can replace `testing` with `stable` for Wheezy. Named distributions ie `jessie` or `wheezy` are ok too. Both the `main` and `non-free` components are necessary since one of `acroread`'s dependencies is `acroread-debian-files` which is in `main`. Instead of using the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, I actually use a separate file in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory - `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deb-multimedia.list`. **Here is a one off command to create the file (can be copy/pasted into a terminal):**

```
echo 'deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org testing main non-free' |
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deb-multimedia.list
```

If you do not want to use any of the other www.debian-multimedia.org repository packages, you can give a lower priority than the Debian packages of the same name by adding the following lines to the **top of `/etc/apt/preferences`:**

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing, o=Unofficial Multimedia Packages
Pin-Priority: 120
```

Again `testing` can be swapped for `stable` here or named distributions can be used with `n=jessie` or `n=wheezy`.

To make www.debian-multimedia.org a trusted source, you can install its keyring package:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring
```

If you are running 64-bit, you may need to add the `i386` architecture as Adobe currently doesn't do 64-bit builds of Reader for Linux. To check if the `i386` architecture has already been added, you can do:

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

**And to add it:**

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

**Installation is as simple as:**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install acroread
```

---

Now the problem that I have with running `acroread` is this error:

```
/usr/lib/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

One way to get around this is to use the following script to run `acroread`:

```
#!/bin/sh

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu /usr/bin/acroread
```

If you put this in `/usr/local/bin` (which appears before `/usr/bin` in the default `PATH`), the script will take priority over the actual `acroread` binary. This should fix running Reader from the command line and from the menu.

For those who are not comfortable adding the script (or who just want a quick way to do it), you can copy and paste the following into a terminal to add the fix:

```
echo '#!/bin/sh

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu /usr/bin/acroread' >acroread

sudo install acroread /usr/local/bin
rm acroread
```

An alternative workaround is to do what is suggested here - http://forums.solydxk.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1754:

```
cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 libGL.so.1
```

This is may be a better option if you want to try to get the browser plugin to work, although the `/usr/local/bin` should be less intrusive and easier to remember and remove when it is no longer required.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to take the package for Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE) and install that instead. LMDE is based on and 100% compatible with Debian testing. You can safely mix LMDE and Debian repositories on a single system.

So, since LMDE packages acroread, you can install it by adding their repo to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/multimedia testing main non-free
```

Once you have added that line, update the sources and install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

---

#### NOTE:

LMDE is 100% compatible with Debian, **not** Ubuntu, this solution works for Debian but may or may not work for Ubuntu.

---

For LMDE, I install with `apt-get install acroread` with these in my sources.list:

```
deb http://lmde-mirror.gwendallebihan.net/latest testing main contrib non-free 
deb http://lmde-mirror.gwendallebihan.net/latest/multimedia testing main non-free
deb http://lmde-mirror.gwendallebihan.net/latest/security testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ debian main upstream import romeo
```

Comment: Just tested this and I still have the same problem with the current LMDE version. The problem seems to be that the location of certain libraries have changed, rather than something in the package having changed. The package will only have been tested with other LMDE latest packages.

Comment: @Graeme what problem? I install it perfectly well on my LMDE with `apt-get install acroread` and using the sources shown in my updated answer.

Comment: The problem (and workaround) I have detailed in my answer. I get this error when I run it: `/usr/lib/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. The last update pack for LMDE was released in September, so you installation will not be the same as Jessie. This will be why you don't have the problem. Either that or my combination of installed packages.

Comment: Please the the note added at the top of my answer. The LMDE multimedia repository is a copy of the same repo which is no longer recommended by Debian. You might want to add a similar note.

Comment: @Graeme is it? I think it is completely independent and maintained by Mint, why do you think it's the same as the old debian multimedia one?

Comment: I am almost completely sure, yes. Check the top of the release files for each, label, origin and description are exactly the same - http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/multimedia/dists/testing/Release and http://www.deb-multimedia.org/dists/testing/Release. Plus the release cycle is the same as with the rest of LMDE - you wouldn't get this if they were doing their own packaging.

Comment: The source link here is depreciated. It does not work in Debian 8.5.