# How can I install Adobe Reader in Fedora 20?

Tags: fedora, software-installation

Since it is no longer available on https://get.adobe.com/fr/reader/otherversions/

I'm not able to find an appropriate RPM to install adobe reader. Does anybody have a good way for installing it? The system is 64-bit.

Comment: Just download it from adobe.com, imho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux version of the Adobe Reader has reached EOL. You can still download it however via these links. The details of all this are discussed in this IF!10 post titled: [Install Adobe Reader on Fedora 20/19, CentOS/RHEL 7/6.5/5.10](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-adobe-acrobat-pdf-reader-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/).

- http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/i386/adobe-release-i386-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
- http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/i386/flash-plugin-11.2.202.400-release.i386.rpm
- http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/i386/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i486linux_enu.rpm
- http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/x86_64/adobe-release-x86_64-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
- http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/x86_64/flash-plugin-11.2.202.400-release.x86_64.rpm

The EOL is discussed here on the Adobe website: [One Year from Now: Adobe Reader and Acrobat 9 EOL](http://blogs.adobe.com/adobereader/2012/06/one-year-from-now-adobe-reader-and-acrobat-9-eol.html). It was dated June 8th, 2012.

To install it, I did the following:

```
$ sudo yum localinstall \
  http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/i386/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i486linux_enu.rpm
```

**NOTE:** You may encounter issues with this package and might not be able to install it. I, for example, have HipChat installed and this package conflicted with that one, and I was unable to install `acroread`.

All is not lost if you encounter this issue, however. You can navigate to this URL: ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/, and download a tarball of `acroread`, and attempt to install that where ever you desire.

Much of this was covered in my answer to this other U&L question titled: [How to install Adobe Acrobat Reader in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3505/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-in-debian).

Answer (score 1):

*32-bit*

```
# yum -y localinstall http://web.archive.org/http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/adobe-release/adobe-release-i386-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

*64-bit*

```
# yum -y localinstall http://web.archive.org/http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/adobe-release/adobe-release-x86_64-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

*Install*

```
# yum -y install nspluginwrapper.i686 AdobeReader_enu
```