# How to Install adobe reader-enu in 64-bit Debian 8.5?

Tags: debian, pdf, acrobat-reader

Situation: to have Advanced search (like Adobe Acrobat's one) in any pdf reader; search many documents and have integrated view for their review

I know the thread about installing Adobe reader by in the thread [How to install Adobe Acrobat Reader in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3505/16920) where I tried

- its current accepted answer is about the installation of the old version (9.0) of Adobe reader [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110207/16920)
- terdon's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110289/16920) about adding Linux Mint's reporisitory of `acroread` in Debian but the source does not work

I know the answer in the thread [How to Install Adobe Acrobat in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/a/805399/25388) about adding a repository, but there is no command `add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner"` in Debian. 
I can recall that you can get Adobe Reader 10 and/or newer by this method. 
I would like to get at least the same in Debian.

OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Architecture: amd64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe Reader is no longer supported by Adobe on Linux since 2014. Adobe no longer provides security updates for Adobe Reader under Linux.

> How to Install adobe reader-enu in 64-bit Debian 8.5?

```
wget ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 lib32nss-mdns libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libstdc++6:i386
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: OTOH, [Adobe Reader for Windows seems to run fine in wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27093).

Comment: @MatteoItalia It would be nice if such VBs could be done with minimal memory and minimal interface. - - Current environment is just not sufficient for my tasks in isolated environment. - - It would be nice to understand why Advanced search cannot be implemented for any pdf reader in Linux.

Comment: You're not actually installing the 64-bit version using this approach 
It's so clear that the package is 32-bit and installing the extra packages  won't actually make any change to that

Answer (score 5):

The last version of Adobe Reader available on Linux is 9.5.5, even in [Canonical's partner repository](http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/acroread/). Adobe Reader has been unsupported on Linux for quite a while, I dare say there are probably a few security vulnerabilities lurking...

You should use [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) or [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince).

If you need features which are only available in Adobe Reader, you should run it in a virtual machine to reduce the level of risk; either version 9.5.5 in a Linux VM, or the current release in a Windows VM (assuming you have the appropriate license). If you take the Linux VM route, you might as well make it a 32-bit VM since that will simplify the installation of Adobe Reader (`gdebi` will do the right thing on its own, see [GAD3R's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309332/86440)).

Comment: You should mention that in your question... If you need features which are unique to Adobe Reader (and I think multi-document search is indeed not available anywhere else, even [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/)) then you need to run Adobe Reader. To reduce the risk, you should run it in a VM — either the old 9.5.5 release in a Linux VM, or (if you have a Windows license) the current release in a Windows VM.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Debian, but I'm guessing this would work ... I got it to install in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS / Mint 18 by doing the following with elevated permissions (e.g. sudo, su root, etc.):

```
# add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner"   
# apt update
```

Search for the acroreader package using apt after adding the archive repository (where it is located):

```
# apt search adobereader
```

There are a few different language versions, such as -enu (English), -deu (German), -fra (French) and -jp (Japanese).  I chose English, so I'll use that in my example.

But first, you have to install a couple required libraries:

```
# apt install libatk-adaptor:i386 libgail-common:i386
```

Then install the package itself:

```
# apt install adobereader-enu
```

Without being root (e.g. don't type sudo), invoke the following at prompt to load the program:

```
$ acroread
```

Takes a while to run for the first time because it loads a license / TOS it wants you to agree to.  You only have to do this once.

Seems to work pretty good despite the dodgy 32-bit libraries.  Works better than the version available in the Arch Linux AUR (which takes a fair bit of hacking) which I used for work for nearly a year without problem.

Hope that helps...