# How to accomplish print link action of LaTeX in Linux Adobe?

Tags: debian, pdf, printing, printer, acrobat-reader

We can create the action which works in Windows and OSX, based on the thread answer [How to add print link action of specific pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372584/13173) 
The reason why only Windows and OSX is supported is that only the recent Adobe Acrobat Javascript [API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJSPreface%2FJS_API_AcroJSPreface.htm) support `PrintParams`. 
However, Linux has many PDF viewers so I am thinking if to make such a support for Linux can be possible or if it exists there in any form. 
Basically, the LaTeX code uses mediabutton calls to the `print()`.

OS: Debian 9
TeXLive: 2017
PDF viewer: Adobe `acroread` installed like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309332/16920)

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no other JavaScript-aware PDF viewer on Linux than the old and un-maintained AdobeReader-9.5

Comment: @AlexG What is the format to have dynamic visualisations in Linux? - - I am thinking to prototype basic dynamics.

Comment: What do you mean with 'dynamic visualisations'?

Comment: @AlexG There are user groups: doctor, nurse and assistant in shifts day, evening and night. When Day fills out the blanket, it gives some pieces of information to the evening shift. I want to pass this piece of information to the evening form. But I am unsure how to visualise it efficiently.

Comment: Still have no idea what you are after and what it has to do with the subject (PDF/printing/acrobat).

Comment: @AlexG I am testing the basic visualisation functions for prototyping in Linux. Print is just an example function that is required.