# How to scroll pages 1,..,N-1 and show page N in PDF viewer?

Tags: debian, pdf, browser, acrobat-reader

I want to show two pages of a pdf document at the same time in PDF viewer such that

1. be able to scroll pages 1,..,N-1 at the left-hand-side view
2. show all the time page N at the rigth hand-side view

The reason is that I am inputing data on pages 1,..,N-1 from the user, while the page N aggregates the data on page N. 
So I want to show all the time the last page. 
Maybe, it is possible somehow in some internet browser.

OS: Debian 9
PDF viewer: any PDF viewer, but preferably Adobe `acroread` with Javascript installed like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309332/16920)
Internet browsers: Firefox 52.2.x, Google Chrome 59.x